# How can save XSRF token from cookie and pass it to server in next request header in Gatling

Tags: scala, load-testing, gatling

I'm trying to perform a load test with Gatling, and I need to save `X-XSRF-TOKEN` from cookie and pass it in the next request header. this is my scenario:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._
import scala.util.Random

class addvehicle extends Simulation {

    object randomIntegerGenerator {
        def randomInteger(range: Int) =
            scala.util.Random.nextInt(range).toString
    }
    val feeder = Array(
        Map( "Authorization" -> "Bearer XXXX" ),
        Map( "Authorization" -> "Bearer YYYY" )
    ).random

    val httpProtocol = http
        .baseUrl("https://192.168.165.176:30479")
        .inferHtmlResources()
        .acceptHeader("application/json, text/plain, */*")
        .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
        .acceptLanguageHeader("IR")
        .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0")
    val headers_8 = Map("X-XSRF-TOKEN" -> "f50b2810-ee6a-435b-87d6-5a40dd45bbb1")

    val headers_9 = Map(
        "Content-Type" -> "application/json",
        "Origin" -> "https://192.168.165.176:30479"

    val headers_10 = Map(
        "Content-Type" -> "application/json",
        "Origin" -> "https://192.168.165.176:30479"

    val headers_11 = Map("X-XSRF-TOKEN" -> "050e6282-febd-4452-a68b-e88fbc8d3134")

    val req = s"""{"entryDate":"2020-10-03","vehicleVersion":"vehicleVersionValue"]}"""

    var randomSession = Iterator.continually(
        Map(
            "randsession" -> (req
                .replace("vehicleVersionValue", randomIntegerGenerator.randomInteger(10))
                )
        ))

    val scn = scenario("addvehicle")
        .feed(feeder)
        .feed(randomSession)
        .pause(1)
        .exec(
            http("request_8")
                .get("/find/usable?category=Vehicle")
                .header("Authorization","${Authorization}")
                .headers(headers_8))
        .pause(1)
        .exec(getCookieValue(CookieKey("XSRF-TOKEN").saveAs("X-XSRF-TOKEN")))
        .exec(
            http("request_9")
                .post("/api/universal/search")
                .header("Authorization","${Authorization}")
                .header("X-XSRF-TOKEN","${X-XSRF-TOKEN}")
                .headers(headers_9)
                .body(ElFileBody("C:/Users/test/Downloads/Gatling/user-files/resources/addvehicle/0009_request.json")))
        .pause(1)
        .exec(getCookieValue(CookieKey("XSRF-TOKEN").saveAs("X-XSRF-TOKEN1")))
        .exec(
            http("request_10")
                .post("/api/vehicle/create")
                .header("Authorization","${Authorization}")
                .header("X-XSRF-TOKEN","${X-XSRF-TOKEN1}")
                .headers(headers_10)
                .body(StringBody("""${randsession}"""))
                .resources(http("request_11")
                    .get("/api/bank/find")
                    .header("Authorization","${Authorization}")
                    .headers(headers_11),
                    http("request_12")
                        .get("/api/vehicle/find?page=0&size=6&sort=createdDate,DESC")
                        .header("Authorization","${Authorization}")
                        .headers(headers_11)))

    setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(5))).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

I want to save `X-XSRF-TOKEN` from request 8 cookie and pass it to server in request 9 header, how can I use `check()` and `saveAs()` API in this scenario to perform load test more than one time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use a `header` or `headerRegex` [check](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_check) to parse the `Set-Cookie` header, or `getCookieValue` [action](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_helpers/) to get the cookie value.

Comment: Our server store `X-XSRF-TOKEN` in browser cookie and expect it in next request header, I tried to use `.exec(getCookieValue(CookieKey("X-XSRF-TOKEN")).saveAs("X-XSRF-TOKEN"))` before next request to store `X-XSRF-TOKEN` but there is as error: `value saveAs is not a member of io.gatling.http.action.cookie.GetCookieValueBuilder`

Comment: misplaced comma: .exec(getCookieValue(CookieKey("X-XSRF-TOKEN").saveAs("X-XSRF-TOKEN"))).

Comment: I added `.exec` to my scenario, but when I print the session, both `$X-XSRF-TOKEN` and `$X-XSRF-TOKEN1` have the same value.

Comment: I flushed the session cookie after saving the cookie and it works! thank you.